# Scrape Remote Registry and report on credential providers

Tags: powershell

I'm not too hot at Powershell however I'm looking for a solution where by I can report on the credential providers being used by PC and Servers in my Windows Domain.

I had found https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Detect-Authentication-09b0a749 (note: this is not being used below) which works fine on a current session, however I want my script to run remotely against all Window OS computers and produce a report.

I want to output the username, provider used (based on the regkey value which corresponds to a provider) and the computer used. If a computer can't be connected to I would like it to gracefully inform of the failure. I feel that 'simply' scanning the registry for specific keys and outputting them seemed to work well however my script has encountered a few issues:

- It appears the $KeyCheck1/2 isn't working. If SessionData\1 exists the script runs fine, where this doesn't it fails to find the key and errors...
- I have a few of different providers in use, hence the 'If $Provider ='. The problem is this doesn't seem to be picking up the value as it always returns the same result (Duo Secure)!
- For some reason my output is dropping the value of $RemotePC

For now I am just using write-host to see what is happening, eventually I want this to email the results (I 'should' be ok with that but any tips may ease things along)

Any advise would be appreciated.

```
Get-Adcomputer -filter {OperatingSystem -like "Windows 7 Ent*"} -properties DNSHostName | ForEach-Object {"$($_.DNSHostName)"} | Out-file -FilePath "U:\Computers.txt"

$filePath = "U:\Computers.txt"

$computerList = Get-Content $filePath

foreach($RemotePC in $computerList){

    if((Test-Connection -ComputerName $remotePC -Count 1 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue)) {
    $session = New-PSSession -ComputerName $RemotePC
    Invoke-Command -Session $Session -ScriptBlock{

        $KeyCheck1 = 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Authentication\LogonUI\SessionData\1'
        $KeyExists1 = Test-Path $KeyCheck1 -IsValid
        If ($KeyExists1 -eq $True) 
            {
            $key1 = 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Authentication\LogonUI\SessionData\1'
            $Provider = (Get-ItemProperty -Path $key1 -Name LastLoggedOnProvider)
            $User = (Get-ItemProperty -Path $key1 -Name LoggedOnSAMUser).LoggedOnSAMUser

            $Provider = (Get-ItemProperty -Path $key1 | Select LastLoggedOnProvider)
            $User = (Get-ItemProperty -Path $key1 | Select LoggedOnSAMUser).LoggedOnSAMUser

            If ($Provider = '{449B5F65-C836-4EB0-A00A-71C47EF75210}')
                {
                $UsedProvider = "Duo Secure"
                }
            ElseIf ($Provider = '{8bf9a910-a8ff-457f-999f-a5ca10b4a885}')
                {
                $UsedProvider = "Smart Card"
                }
            ElseIf ($Provider = '{8FD7E19C-3BF7-489B-A72C-846AB3678C96}')
                {
                $UsedProvider = "SmartCard" 
                }
            ElseIf ($Provider = '{25CBB996-92ED-457e-B28C-4774084BD562}')
                {
                $UsedProvider = "Password Only!"
                }
            Write-host $User used $UsedProvider on $RemotePC
            }
    Else 
        {
        $KeyCheck2 = 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Authentication\LogonUI\SessionData\2'
        $KeyExists2 = Test-Path $KeyCheck2 -IsValid
        If ($KeyExists2 -eq $True)
            {
            $key2 = 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Authentication\LogonUI\SessionData\2'
            $Provider = (Get-ItemProperty -Path $key2 -Name LastLoggedOnProvider)
            $User = (Get-ItemProperty -Path $key2 -Name LoggedOnSAMUser).LoggedOnSAMUser

            $Provider = (Get-ItemProperty -Path $key2 | Select LastLoggedOnProvider)
            $User = (Get-ItemProperty -Path $key2 | Select LoggedOnSAMUser).LoggedOnSAMUser

            If ($Provider = '{449B5F65-C836-4EB0-A00A-71C47EF75210}')
                {
                $UsedProvider = "Duo Secure"
                }
            ElseIf ($Provider = '{8bf9a910-a8ff-457f-999f-a5ca10b4a885}')
                {
                $UsedProvider = "Smart Card"
                }
            ElseIf ($Provider = '{8FD7E19C-3BF7-489B-A72C-846AB3678C96}')
                {
                $UsedProvider = "SmartCard" 
                }
            ElseIf ($Provider = '{25CBB996-92ED-457e-B28C-4774084BD562}')
                {
                $UsedProvider = "Password Only!"
                }
            Write-host $User used $UsedProvider on $RemotePC
            }
        }   
    }
Remove-PSSession $session
}
Else
    {    

    }
}
```

Comment: `Invoke-Command` does not get its variables from the remote environment, so within the block, `$RemotePC` is empty. From PowerShell 3 onwards, you can use `$using:var` to remote values that way; prior to that, you have to pass arguments to the script block explicitly. (Or you could just use `$env:computername`.)

Comment: I would also looking into `switch`es to replace your if blocks!

Comment: You have multiple issues here. First is that `$Provider = '{449B5F65-C836-4EB0-A00A-71C47EF75210}'` is not checking for equality. That is an assignment statement. Use `$Provider -eq '{449B5F65-C836-4EB0-A00A-71C47EF75210}'`

Comment: `$Provider = (Get-ItemProperty -Path $key1 | Select LastLoggedOnProvider)` would get expected results if you expand the property `$Provider = (Get-ItemProperty -Path $key1).LastLoggedOnProvider` like you did in other variables.

Comment: Related to my last comment `ForEach-Object {"$($_.DNSHostName)"}` is you trying to get the string data and not an object property. You dot notation as you already have and I have mentioned or you could use `Select-Object -Expand PropertyName`

Comment: Thanks Jeroen Mostert - computer names are now returning

Comment: Matt, I'll look into switches, the provider is not returning anything after including the .LastLoggedOnProvider and using -eq instead. As for the computer name retrieval, this works fine as-is.